# Are web workers preemptive or not?

Tags: multitasking, web-worker

I guess `web workers` are not preemptive. Otherwise I do not understand how they can be terminated with `terminate` API. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Web workers do not preempt anything from the main window.

It's a message based event model. So you can call terminate from the main window and depending on where the worker is in it's execution, you may or may not receive the last message.

Assuming you have some sort of producer, consumer model.